# how to intercept horizontal flings on children of an android ListView

Tags: android, android-listview, motionevent, android-gesture, android-scroll

I'd like to respond to horizontal "fling" gestures on individual cells in a vertically scrolling ListView.  Currently I've accomplished this by using a GestureDetector for each cell view in the list.

I'm noticing, though, that it's much harder to actually get a horizontal "fling" to register with one of the cell views than if they were just stuck in a non-scrolling linear layout.

For instance, if I tap down inside a cell then drag my finger "up and to the right" fairly quickly this is recognized as a fling in the non-scrolling case, but isn't recognized in the scrolling case.

I've experimented with sub-classing ListView and overriding onInterceptTouchEvent, then I can't seem to get it right. What I would *like* to have happen is for gestures that will eventually be recognized as "flings" on a child view to be ignored by the scroll view.  I would want to limit these based on the "angle" of the gesture, i.e. the ratio of the Y distance to the X distance.  If that ratio is sufficiently high then its a "vertical" fling and the ListView should handle it.  If that ratio is sufficiently low then it's a "horizontal" fling and the ListView should ignore it and allow a child view to handle it.

Can anyone provide some perspective on how this might be accomplished?  I'm assuming I'll going to have to do something clever in the onInterceptTouchEvent method of the ListView sub-class.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
final ListView v = new ListView(this);
ArrayAdapter<String> a = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);
a.add("one");
a.add("two");
a.add("three");
a.add("four");
v.setAdapter(a);

OnGestureListener ogl = new SimpleOnGestureListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
        if (Math.abs(velocityX) > Math.abs(velocityY)) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onFling " + v.pointToPosition((int) e1.getX(), (int) e1.getY()));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
};
final GestureDetector detector = new GestureDetector(ogl);
OnTouchListener otl = new OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        return detector.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
};
v.setOnTouchListener(otl);
OnItemClickListener oicl = new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onItemClick " + position);
    }
};
v.setOnItemClickListener(oicl);
setContentView(v);
```